# Matlab position 0 is off the screen

Tags: windows, matlab

I'm running Matlab 2015a on a Windows 7 laptop connected to two external monitors using nvidia's nView desktop manager. Recently, my figure positions have been screwey. When I set a positive x position, the figures appear off the right side of the screens. Pulling them in view (with Windows Key + Arrow) shows a negative value for anything in view. This is a big problem for my default positions (Waitbars and such are appearing out of view) and if I share my scripts with anyone (otherwise I'd just set my figures to show up at [ -1000, 10, w, l], but that'd put them off the left of other people's screens)

Any ideas what might cause this? I've had the same computer/moniter/GPU set up for over a year, and this only popped up in the past few weeks.

Comment: position in pixels i assume?! what happens if you try to reference it with normalized?

Comment: Yes, that position is in pixels. I describe the behavior normalized in more detail in my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

this might help: [1,1] is the position of the lower left corner of your Main Display. Its not the most left nor the first montior. you can check and change taht in control panel/Display/Settings (or similiar depending on windows version and language). So if your main screen is in the middle the display on the left of it will have a negative value on x

Comment: Nope, 1,1 does not seem to be the lower left of my main display. I have the right most display as the main, and (with normalized units), that monitor is between -2 and -1. The middle is -3 to -2, and the left is -4 to -3. If I change my main monitor to the left most monitor, the right is 0-1, middle is -1 to 0, and left is -2 to -1. It seems like my main monitor always starts at -2 (normalized).